# Updates to the JVM Specification

Tags: java, jvm

JVM Spec 2nd Edition is dated by 1999. Which important updates since then (like dynamicinvoke) should I consider to learn? This is in course to understand internals of the modern JVM implementations (HotSpot particularly).

Comment: The JVM Spec doesn't cover internals of the JVM, that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this link 
http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Publications+JKU
There you will get update about latest research areas.

Answer (score 1):

JSR 924: JavaTM Virtual Machine Specification

This site has the latest version drafts: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=924

The Java™ Virtual Machine Specification Java SE 7 Edition DRAFT 2011-04-15

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr336/index.html http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_se-7-final-spec/index.html

UPDATE:
The Final version of the Java SE 7 Specification PDFs is here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Answer (score 0):

The final JVM specification for Java SE 7 is available here: [JVM specification for Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)