# JVM specification, is there any more recent one?

Tags: java, jvm

I am looking for a more recent versions of JVM specifications, an JVM internals, unfortunately all I was able to found were quite old books from last century...

Does anyone know where to find a newer informations?

Comment: Related (but without an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493322/updates-to-the-jvm-specification

Comment: There is [The Java VM Spec, 3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Language-Specification-James-Gosling/dp/0321246780/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1326967835&sr=8-2) but it's from 2005, so it likely doesn't cover the latest version (it probably doesn't say anything about `invokevirtual` added in Java 7).

Comment: It should cover `invokevirtual` as it was in Java 1.0.  Perhaps you were thinking of `invokedynamic` ;)

Comment: The JVM has changed very little since it was created. If you read understand any version it will be 99% accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSR 924: JavaTM Virtual Machine Specification

This site has the latest version drafts:
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=924

The Java™ Virtual Machine Specification
Java SE 7 Edition DRAFT 2011-04-15

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr336/index.html
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_se-7-final-spec/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The final JVM specification for Java SE 7 is available here: [JVM specification for Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)